# RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid argument

Tags: pytorch

It can run epoch 1 and eval successfully, but it fails when run epoch 2.

```
Train Epoch:1[655200/655800(100%)] loss:26.4959 lr:0.2050
Test Epoch:1 acc:0.973 val:0.895

Train Epoch:2[0/655800(0%)] loss:26.8068 lr:0.2051
File "train_11w.py", line 244, in main
    train(train_loader, model, optimizer, epoch, lr_decay_type, logger, args.log_interval, args)
  File "train_11w.py", line 305, in train
    prediction, ex, exnorm = model(img, mode=6, y=label)
  File "/home/luban/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/luban/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 143, in forward
    outputs = self.parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs)
  File "/home/luban/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 153, in parallel_apply
    return parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs, self.device_ids[:len(replicas)])
  File "/home/luban/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 83, in parallel_apply
    raise output
RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid argument
```

```
Driver Version: 418.67
CUDA Version 10.0.130
python 2.7.3
torch 1.0.0
```

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is difficult to understand what's going wrong, I would suggest you do the following.

1. Can you try to run your code with `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1 python script_name args`? The `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1` env variable makes sure to call all CUDA operations synchronously so that an error message should point to the right line of code in the stack trace.
2. Try setting `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark` to `True/False` to check if it works.
3. Train the model without using DataParallel.
4. Check if you set `drop_last=True` while creating DataLoader, does training work?

Comment: when I add CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1, it also failed with errors.